# Phone Number Authentication for Firebase Through Unity (C#)

Tags: c#, firebase, unity-game-engine, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to get phone number authentication for Unity up and running but I am getting no SMS response. The documentation online is super unclear about how to do this. I'd much rather have Google Auth for Firebase but apparently it isn't supported yet. Can anyone help me figure out how to get this up and running?

Here is what I have so far...

```
public class SignIn : MonoBehaviour {

private string phoneNumber;
private string secureCode;
private uint phoneAuthTimeoutMs;
private Firebase.Auth.FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;
private Credential credential;
private string verificationId;
private string verificationCode;

public Text PhoneNumberInputFieldText;
public Text SecureCodeInputFieldText;
public Button SendSecureCodeButton;
public Button SubmitSecureCodeButton;

// Use this for initialization
void Start()
{
    SendSecureCodeButton.GetComponent<Button>().onClick.AddListener(() => StartSignIn());



}
// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {

}

void StartSignIn()
{
    firebaseAuth = Firebase.Auth.FirebaseAuth.DefaultInstance;
    phoneAuthTimeoutMs = 60000;
    phoneNumber = PhoneNumberInputFieldText.text;
    Debug.Log(phoneNumber);

    if (PlayerPrefs.GetString("secureCode") != null)
    {
        verificationId = PlayerPrefs.GetString("secureCode");
    }
    PhoneAuthProvider provider = PhoneAuthProvider.GetInstance(firebaseAuth);
    provider.VerifyPhoneNumber(phoneNumber, phoneAuthTimeoutMs, null,
      verificationCompleted: (credential) =>
      {
          // Auto-sms-retrieval or instant validation has succeeded (Android only).
          // There is no need to input the verification code.
          // `credential` can be used instead of calling GetCredential().
      },
      verificationFailed: (error) =>
      {
          // The verification code was not sent.
          // `error` contains a human readable explanation of the problem.
      },
      codeSent: (id, token) =>
      {
          //Prompt here to type in SecureCode
          PlayerPrefs.SetString("secureCode", id);


          credential = provider.GetCredential(verificationId, verificationCode);

          firebaseAuth.SignInWithCredentialAsync(credential).ContinueWith(task => {
              if (task.IsFaulted)
              {
                  Debug.LogError("SignInWithCredentialAsync encountered an error: " +
                                  task.Exception);
                  return;
              }

              FirebaseUser newUser = task.Result;
              Debug.Log("User signed in successfully");
              // This should display the phone number.
              Debug.Log("Phone number: " + newUser.PhoneNumber);
              // The phone number providerID is 'phone'.
              Debug.Log("Phone provider ID: " + newUser.ProviderId);
          });

          // Verification code was successfully sent via SMS.
          // `id` contains the verification id that will need to passed in with
          // the code from the user when calling GetCredential().
          // `token` can be used if the user requests the code be sent again, to
          // tie the two requests together.
      },
      codeAutoRetrievalTimeOut: (id) =>
      {
          // Called when the auto-sms-retrieval has timed out, based on the given
          // timeout parameter.
          // `id` contains the verification id of the request that timed out.
      });


}
```

}

Thanks in advance!

Here is my Firebase Console:

[image]

Comment: What does your logcat says? Cause maybe it doesn't working because the phone number isn't registered yet on the firebase.

Comment: It outputs  "Phone Number: 1-888-XXX-XXXX"  and "Phone Provider ID: " Not actual X's just some other numbers. I imagine it is a Google number. I believe it comes from the task.Result.

Answer (score 0):

I'll post an answer but i'll edit this.

Try a simplier sending SMS phone verification

```
Firebase.Auth.FirebaseAuth auth = Firebase.Auth.FirebaseAuth.DefaultInstance;
phoneNumber = "your phone number here";//state the phone number here first
uint phoneAuthTimeoutMs = 10000;
PhoneAuthProvider provider = PhoneAuthProvider.GetInstance(auth);
provider.VerifyPhoneNumber(phoneNumber, phoneAuthTimeoutMs,null,
    verificationCompleted: (credential) => {

    },
    verificationFailed: (error) => {

    },
    codeSent: (id, token) => {
        MyText.text = "SMS Has been sent " + id;
    },
    codeAutoRetrievalTimeOut : (id) => {

    });
MyText.text += "HMM";
```

Then please tell me if it works. Now if it works we will proceed to the next step

Comment: I see "HMM" but nothing else. No SMS received.

Comment: Did you register the number from the firebase??

Comment: Oh! We haven't made the newUser yet so we need to have it already added to Firebase, correct?

Comment: So how would I create a user in Firebase by phone number?

Comment: To sign in users by SMS, you must first enable the Phone Number sign-in method for your Firebase project:  open the Authentication section in the `firebase console` and On the Sign-in Method page, enable the Phone Number sign-in method.

Comment: I have done that part, but it still only asks for Email and Password when I click Add User

Comment: No there's a tab there that you need to enable the Phone Number Verification and Put your Number in it.

Comment: From your project -> Authentication then from authentication there will be 4 tabs above . User , Sign-in Method, Templates, Usage . Go to Sign-In Method then from there enable the phone number

Comment: The switch under "Email and Password" It goes greenish/blue when on?

Comment: Yes, I have it on but it doesn't allow me to add a user with a phone number.

Comment: Wow . But on me i just enabled it right now and it allows me.

Comment: Yes, my "Add User" button only allows me to use Email and Password. Could I be missing something in Unity?